# How to check if a column value is within a range of another two for each row in data table

Tags: r, data.table, intervals

I am now working on a R problem and in my last step, I would like to check if my 95% confidence intervals contain the true values of parameters. I have a question in this step.

```r
dat <- data.table(low = c(0.9, 1.1, 1, 0.95),
                  up = c(0.99, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4),
                  true = c(1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.5))
```

For example, in the first line, I would like to check if the true value 1, is with the confidence interval 0.9 to 0.99. Obviously not so return 0. After examining by row. The desired results will be:

```r
result <- data.table(low = c(0.9, 1.1, 1, 0.95),
                     up = c(0.99, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4),
                     true = c(1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.5), 
                     conv = c(0, 1, 1, 0))
print(result)
```

Is there any efficient way I could solve this problem? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works idiomatically in `data.table`

```
dat[, inConf := ifelse(true >= low & true <= up,T,F)]

###alternatively with 0,1
dat[, inConf := ifelse(true >= low & true <= up,1,0)]
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much for your help. I would like to make it clearer, in the data.table, the command involving only column name will be executed automatically by row, right?

Answer (score 4):

The most efficient way is probably the `between` operator:

```
> result[, conv2 := as.integer(true %between% .(low, up))]
> result
    low   up true conv conv2
1: 0.90 0.99 1.00    0     0
2: 1.10 1.20 1.15    1     1
3: 1.00 1.30 1.20    1     1
4: 0.95 1.40 1.50    0     0
```

You can skip the `as.integer` to get a logical column, which is more standard when encoding such data in R.

The `between` function I'm using here comes from data.table and has two syntaxes:

```
x %between% list(dn, up)
between(x, dn, up)
```

Inside `DT[...]` you can shorten `list()` to `.()`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much for your help. Would you please explain a little bit more about %between% and .(). The command %between% is not what I thought from dplyr, right?

Comment: dat[, conv2 := true %between% .(low, up)]

Comment: @QiangSuper Cool, glad it's helpful. I'm not familiar with the dplyr function, but have added a little explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The %between% command is similar to %in%, which is also from dplyr.

Comment: @QiangSuper I think that function is from base R. If I type `help("%in%")` after loading dplyr 0.7.8, I am directed to a help page with {base} on the first line instead of {dplyr}, anyways.